# Sql multiple row based select like GraphQL

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I have a large table i want to select different columns based on multiple conditions, rather than the entire column even if the row doesn't need it.
something like :
i want (H1,H2) if HR1=R1 and (H2,H3) if H1=R2 ...
problem is i can do a complete select to select all columns needed but that's too much uneeded columns
tried

```
select from ((select H2,H3 where H1=R1),(select H2,H4 where H1=R2), (select H5 where H1=R3))
```

after a certain number of the conditions in the query i get an empty result.

```
| H1 | H2 | H3  | H4  | H5  |
|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
| R1 |[V1]|[V2] | V3  | V4  |
| R2 |[V5]| V6  |[V7] | V8  |
| R3 | V9 | V10 | V11 |[V12]|
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want this :

```
select  case when H1 in (R1,R2) then H2 else null end as H2
      , case when H1 = R1 then H3 else null end as H3
      , case when H1 = R2 then H4 else null end as H4
      , case when H1 = R3 then H5 else null end as H5
from table
```